# iOS: Open different view controllers on tap of different cell of tableview throwing exception sometime

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to open different view controllers on tap of different cells of table view. For that, I have made different Segues in Storyboard. Now lets take example,

Total 4 view controllers A, B, C and D.

A contains table view and table view contains 3 cells

On tap of first cell -> B View controller,

On tap of second cell -> C View controller,

On tap of third cell -> D View controller.

I have implemented above functionality like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("B", sender: nil)
    case 1:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("C", sender: nil)
    case 2:
        performSegueWithIdentifier("D", sender: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

And above code works fine. But sometime it throws an exception when I play randomly, One of random way is mentioned below:

1. First Cell to B
2. Back button to A
3. Second cell to C
4. Back button to A
5. Third cell to D
6. Back button to A
7. Second cell to C (Now exception is thrown)

This is one of many scenarios in which app crashes. Sometime it crashes on 4th point or 6th point. And I am getting following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/E57BCF07-1FBB-469C-A99D-56930FAE1AB0/PMD.app> (loaded)' with name 'Gf1-A9-PrY-view-pxD-t4-NUk' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
```

Ideally, It should crashes every time or it shouldn't. But it crashes in some random different ways.

Am I doing something wrong? Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show me your segue method.

Comment: try to avoid to use Main.storyboard ,and creat new storyboard to do it

Comment: @Mr.A, I haven't added any segue method in view controller. I think it is not needed. Right?

Comment: @WilsonXJ, I can't use two storyboards. It will create more complexity for me and I am novice in iPhone development

Comment: Are you loading the storyboard programmatically? Weird it says `.storyboardc` instead of `.storyboard` at the end of the exception. These kind of errors also occur when you have more than one instance of the Storyboard.

Comment: @AlejandroIván, No I don't load storyboard programmatically.

Comment: Another option (never experienced that myself but I've read it happened to some people) is that a badly defined user defined attribute of the view controller avoids it to get loaded and thus the app crashes. Double check them if you can.

Comment: @AlejandroIván, I have removed all user defined attribute of the view controller but still facing same issue.

Comment: can you share your `numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: If you create a segue from static cell of tableview in `storyboard` why would you also call `performSegueWithIdentifier `?

Comment: @Idan, I have created 3 different segues from one view controller to another, not from static cell of tableview